# 2d Context vs WebGL for Rendering Video

Tags: html, video, canvas, webgl

I am currently using the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` to draw video coming from a RTC mediastream to a canvas. Unfortunately, this takes up considerable CPU resources.

Would it be more performant to do this using a `WebGLRenderingContext`? (Hardware acceleration?) If yes, how exactly does one handle this, preferably without creating an in-between video element?

Comment: Are you doing some processing on the image? drawImage should already be hardware accelerated, and should not be so much CPU intensive. I don't know webGL enough, but in my mind you would have to create a texture for each video frame, and I think that creating texture is not made on the GPU. But once again I don't know webGL enough so wait for some authoritative voice in this area.

Comment: No processing, however there are up to 12 RTC mediastreams that need to be shown. Audio is handled quite nicely over the Web Audio API.

Comment: Ah 12 maybe a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Updated :

Source:
https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/e9ee0e48efb6158878dbfe70878d3663f52ab6f7/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/webgl-demo.js#L374

```js
function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    video
  );
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's using Three.js, and is there any vanilla webGL exmaple to render video into canvas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at https://maximumroulette.com/apps/matrix-engine/query-build.html?u=camera_texture

Comment: I will find basic working example in vanilla js. Its not big deal. Take a look a matrix-engine ....

Comment: You are so kind!

Comment: I have post [a question about rendering video directly](  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74190474/how-to-render-a-video-by-webgl-texture-onto-canvsa), if you have time,  please consider checking it ~ Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes i will because it is interest !

Comment: I have done a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vv7bgq?file=useWebGL/index.tsx) to render video by webGL2, and  thanks for your advice and information in this question, help me a lot!

Comment: I just switch canvas2d context with video tag. Great HTML5.