# How to render a video by webGL texture onto canvsa?

Tags: javascript, video, webgl

I'm doing benchmark for video rendering, and I have some trouble in implementing rendering video frame onto canvas by webGL, without any filtering or transoforming.

I have done this with canvas2Dcontext, which directly use the  `CanvasRenderingContext2D .drawImage` API.

But for webGL rendering, I really have a hard time, becasue I lack knowledge about glsl, openGL, and whole thing.

**After searching and test, I have a demo now, which successfully read a video frame into texture and render it. But I fond it wired for 3 things:**

1. **It only render part of the video, likely to be the right part of the video;**
2. **It scales both vertically and horizontally;**
3. **The color looks wired on `Stackbilitz` but looks right on my local vite demo;**

I believe there is some problem in shader glsl or webGL config, but I don't know. I hope if anyone can point out any problem, or give any working exmaple in vanilia js.

Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshoot1]
[image: scrreenshoot2]

Here is my [Stackbilitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-k5n7y8?file=useWebGL/index.tsx),  after video loaded, you can click the `start benchmark` button to trigger render loop. The key logic in inside `useWebGl` folder.

And for our convinence, I paste the *magic* shader glsl here:

```
// texture fragment
precision lowp float;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureOffsetVector;
void main () {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord).rgb, texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord+vTextureOffsetVector).r); // rgb + alpha变化
}
```

```
// texture vertex position
attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureOffsetVector;
uniform vec2 uTextureOffsetVector;
uniform vec4 uScale;
void main () {
  gl_Position = aVertexPosition * uScale;
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
  vTextureOffsetVector = uTextureOffsetVector;
}
```

Comment: I have successfuly implemented it. See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vv7bgq?file=useWebGL/index.tsx)  here. 
But it still works wired if user scales the browser page, I will look at it later.